# OpenId Connect Authentication & Azure AD Scopes Confusion

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to understand the correlation between the scopes I request in the Scope property of OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions and what is returned in my access token.

When I request only "openid profile" I get all the scopes that have been granted consent by the user or admin. Also the version of the access token returned seems to be dependent on the scopes request. For example if I include my registered "api://........". I believe I have both my web app and api configured in the manifest to version 2.

For example: "openid profile" returns the scopes "Directory.Read.All Group.Read.All User.Read profile openid email" in my access token.

Do certain scopes automatically map to others or is there some logic to this? For my own understanding I am trying to find some logical cause and effect to what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you only put "openid profile" in scope, the default scopes in access token "Directory.Read.All Group.Read.All User.Read profile openid email" is for Microsoft Graph API by default. It is by design.

Because this access token is used to [call the UserInfo endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#calling-the-userinfo-endpoint), wherein the user information is actually from Microsoft Graph.

When you put "api://........" in scope, the access token will be for your API application. There is an `aud` claim in the access token, which identifies the intended recipient of the token. You can check that.

Comment: So the act of adding my api://..... scope request overrides the other scopes automatically and signals that the access token be generated for my API only? Also are MS Graph access tokens v1 tokens by default? I have noticed that when it's only a graph token that it is v1. Maybe this doesn't matter but I am curious if I have missed something.

Comment: @MViglainco In general, the first one you put in your `scope` will take effect. For example "api://.....  user.read", the first is for your API while the second one is for Graph. In this case the access token is for your API. But it's not the recommended way to set the `scope`. One token is for one resource. So we should not put multiple permissions which are from different resources. MS Graph access token is v1 by default and can't be changed to v2. Custom API access token can chencge to v2.

Comment: Thanks again. That makes sense. Do you know any resources for how to approach when you need access tokens for multiple resources? If my understanding is correct then it seems impossible. On login you exchange the auth code and client id/secret for an access token. My understanding is that the code is one time use. So how to get other resource token? My refresh token in hand at this point is only valid for the original resource.

Comment: @MViglainco You can use the refresh token in hand to call the `/token` endpoint with "other resource" by specifying the `scope` as "other resource". For example, the access token and refresh token currently is for you own API. You can call the `/token` like this `client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&refresh_token=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq...&grant_type=refresh_token&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh`. In this case the new access token is for Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @MViglainco Refresh token document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token

Comment: Thanks. That is simple and makes sense. I don't see many resources explaining these common scenarios in effective ways.

Comment: Can you provide a link with more information regarding this `aud` claim that you mentioned? What does it stand for, what values are expected to be in it, any reference?